# move_uploaded_file() gives a Owner/Group error

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm using `move_uploaded_file()` to upload images to the server, however it gives the usual error of:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/file.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/newuser/public_html/model/account.class.php on line 39

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move       
'/tmp/phpuLkUgE' to 'upload/file.png' in     
/home/newuser/public_html/model/account.class.php on line 39
```

This is **not permission based** as I have set the folder to 777 with root access and `ls -l` displays it correctly as this.

```
755 /home/newuser/public_html/model
755 /home/newuser/public_html/model/account.class.php
777 /home/newuser/public_html/upload
```

**PHP Line**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/file.png");
```

The problem I think is down to the Owner/Group setting being configured incorrectly .. a while back I had all of my sites as subdomains in one account:

```
/home/olduser/public_html/subdomains/index.html
```

I then changed this and created a new user account to manage a separate website easier and just moved the files across ...

```
/home/olduser/public_html/subdomains
/home/newuser/public_html/index.html
```

The new folders in `/home/newuser` are now owned and grouped as `newuser newuser` but I think php may be running as `nobody olduser` so this could be causing the issue?

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: If you're getting `no such file or directory`, it would seem that the temporary uploaded file doesn't exist at all, hence failed upload, rather than an error actually moving the file.  Post your PHP code.

Comment: @Michael Updated the error codes to provide a clearer understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions to a particular file / directory don't just apply on the directory itself, but on the *whole* path leading up to it.

Example:

```
/home/ - needs 'x' permission (execute)
/home/newuser/ - needs 'x' permission
/home/newuser/public_html/ - needs 'x' permission
/home/newuser/public_html/avatar/ - needs 'wx' permission (execute + write)
```

Comment: The permissions are all as they should be, I'm sure the problem is to do with the Apache REMOTE_USER or Owner/Group

Comment: @Silver89 another possibility might be seLinux

Comment: @Silver89 also, for peace of mind could you add the permissions of `/home` and `/home/newuser` to the post? :)

Comment: For some seriously strange reason `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/file.png");` doesn't work but `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "/home/newuser/public_html/upload/file.png");` does?

Comment: @Silver89 that Is strange ... perhaps it had trouble determining what `..` is? :)

Answer (score 0):

It was kind of touched on indirectly in Silver89's feedback under Jack's Answer, but not outright stated - so I wanted to provide an answer to what helped me with this issue which had me scratching my head for a long time. ;)

The best approach that I have found for the destination of move_uploaded_file() is to use the full absolute path. It can vary based on whether you are on a Unix\Linux server or Windows server, but this should give you the basic idea.

On my Unix server at work, you cannot use "../anything" but have to use the full absolute internal file path of `/var/www/html/uploads/imagename.jpg`.

So that is why your last test worked for you, Silver89 - because your server was probably trying to upload the image to `http://yourservername.com/upload/file.png` instead of `http://www.yourservername.com/yoursubfolder/upload/file.png`. It probably threw out the "../" part altogether and that folder didn't exist on the server.

You can find out what that full path name is by logging onto the server (terminal/ssh etc.) and issuing the 'pwd' command or by using PHP code and echoing the getcwd() command in a stripped php file in the folder where your images will go.

[This site](http://www.bin-co.com/php/articles/current_file_path.php) is helpful in figuring this out based on your server using different PHP Server Config Checking Functions - See the table midway down. You can simply echo these out to the screen such as:

```
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"].
```

This was a tough one for me so I hope this makes it a little easier for the next person to find - even if this is 8 months old. ;)